# is it possible to get the content of a pom.xml file from github api?

Tags: github, github-api

i want to read the content of the pom.xml file because I need the artifactId and groupId. I am running a script that loops through a bunch of GitHub repos, and I don't want to have to clone all the repos and read the pom.xml that way.

Comment: Once you have the relative path of the `pom.xml` in each repo, you should be able to avoid cloning the entire repo by accessing the specific `pom.xml` file at the URL `github.com/<user>/<repo>/blob/<branch>/<path>/pom.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Assuming you using the GraphQL API, here is the snippet which can help you do that

```
repositories(first: 100, after:$after) {
        totalCount
        nodes {
          name
          url
          pom: object(expression: "master:pom.xml") {             
            ... on Blob {
                text
            }
        }
    }
```